# How to get column names with all values null?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I don't have any ideas to get column names when it has null value

For example,

```
case class A(name: String, id: String, email: String, company: String)

val e1 = A("n1", null, "n1@c1.com", null)
val e2 = A("n2", null, "n2@c1.com", null)
val e3 = A("n3", null, "n3@c1.com", null)
val e4 = A("n4", null, "n4@c2.com", null)
val e5 = A("n5", null, "n5@c2.com", null)
val e6 = A("n6", null, "n6@c2.com", null)
val e7 = A("n7", null, "n7@c3.com", null)
val e8 = A("n8", null, "n8@c3.com", null)
val As = Seq(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8)
val df = sc.parallelize(As).toDF
```

This code makes dataframe like this :

```
+----+----+---------+-------+
|name|  id|    email|company|
+----+----+---------+-------+
|  n1|null|n1@c1.com|   null|
|  n2|null|n2@c1.com|   null|
|  n3|null|n3@c1.com|   null|
|  n4|null|n4@c2.com|   null|
|  n5|null|n5@c2.com|   null|
|  n6|null|n6@c2.com|   null|
|  n7|null|n7@c3.com|   null|
|  n8|null|n8@c3.com|   null|
+----+----+---------+-------+
```

and I want to get column names all of their rows are null : id, company

I don't care the type of output. Array, String, RDD whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a simple count on all your columns, then using the indices of the columns that return a count of `0`, you subset `df.columns`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count,col}
// Get column indices
val col_inds = df.select(df.columns.map(c => count(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
                 .collect()(0)
                 .toSeq.zipWithIndex
                 .filter(_._1 == 0).map(_._2)
// Subset column names using the indices
col_inds.map(i => df.columns.apply(i))
//Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(id, company)
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution could be as follows (but am afraid the performance might not be satisfactory).

```
val ids = Seq(
  ("1", null: String), 
  ("1", null: String),
  ("10", null: String)
).toDF("id", "all_nulls")

scala> ids.show
+---+---------+
| id|all_nulls|
+---+---------+
|  1|     null|
|  1|     null|
| 10|     null|
+---+---------+

val s = ids.columns.
  map { c => 
    (c, ids.select(c).dropDuplicates(c).na.drop.count) }. // <-- performance here!
  collect { case (c, cnt) if cnt == 0 => c }
scala> s.foreach(println)
all_nulls
```

Comment: I think that `dropDuplicates(c)` is the point of perfomance lack.
am I right?

Comment: I'm more concerned with iterating over columns and doing the same distributed count for each. That can take some time for many columns and could get faster with parallel job submission (e.g. `ids.columns.par`).