# Spark Get only columns that have one or more null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

From a dataframe I want to get names of columns which contain at least one null value inside.

Considering the dataframe below:

```
val dataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (7, null, 18, 1.0),
  (8, "CA", null, 0.0),
  (9, "NZ", 15, 0.0)
)).toDF("id", "country", "hour", "clicked")
```

I want to get column names 'Country' and 'Hour'.

```
id  country hour    clicked
7   null    18      1
8   "CA"    null    0
9   "NZ"    15      0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is one solution, but it's a bit awkward, I hope there is an easier way:

```
val cols = dataset.columns

val columnsToSelect = dataset
  // count null values (by summing up 1s if its null)
  .select(cols.map(c => (sum(when(col(c).isNull,1))>0).alias(c)):_*)
  .head() // collect result of aggregation
  .getValuesMap[Boolean](cols) // now get columns which are "true"
  .filter{case (c,hasNulls) => hasNulls}
  .keys.toSeq // and get the name of those columns


dataset
  .select(columnsToSelect.head,columnsToSelect.tail:_*)
  .show()
+-------+----+
|country|hour|
+-------+----+
|   null|  18|
|     CA|null|
|     NZ|  15|
+-------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I also expected an easier way to achieve it. Your answer is quicker than mtoto's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48113625/4964651), comparing the counts per column to the number of rows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count,col}
// Get number of rows
val nr_rows = dataset.count
// Get column indices
val col_inds = dataset.select(dataset.columns.map(c => count(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
                 .collect()(0)
                 .toSeq.zipWithIndex
                 .filter(_._1 != nr_rows).map(_._2)
// Subset column names using the indices
col_inds.map(i => dataset.columns.apply(i))
Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(country, hour)
```

Comment: this is quite inefficient as you call `dataset.count` many times