# Idiomatic way to select only those columns containing at least one not null value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the most idiomatic (and efficient) way to select only those DataFrame/DataSet columns, that contain at least one NOT NULL value.

I.e. having the following data set:

```
+----+----+------+----+---------------------+----+
|int1|int2|str1  |str2|dt1                  |dt2 |
+----+----+------+----+---------------------+----+
|1   |null|strin1|null|null                 |null|
|null|null|null  |null|2000-01-03 12:12:12.0|null|
+----+----+------+----+---------------------+----+
```

how would I get the following one:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
|int1|str1  |dt1                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|1   |strin1|null                 |
|null|null  |2000-01-03 12:12:12.0|
+----+------+---------------------+
```

It would be nice to have a solution that is working for Apache Spark version 1.6.0+

Data setup:

```
case class C(int1: Integer, int2: Integer, str1: String, str2: String, dt1: String, dt2: String)

val cc = Seq(
  C(1, null, "strin1", null, null, null),
  C(null, null, null, null, "2000-01-03 12:12:12", null)
)
val t = sc.parallelize(cc, 2).toDF()
val df = t.withColumn("dt1", $"dt1".cast("timestamp")).withColumn("dt2", $"dt2".cast("timestamp"))
```

**UPDATE:**

PS thanks to [@user8371915](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464021/idiomatic-way-to-select-only-those-columns-containing-at-least-one-not-null-valu/48466279#comment83921554_48464021) for pointing to [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110448/how-to-get-column-names-with-all-values-null). I'd like to leave this question open with a hope to find a more elegant solution - I tried to find a way to use something like:

```
df.columns.filter(c => when(count(col(c))>0,c))
```

but i couldn't figure out how to do this properly...

Answer (score 2):

Using [an approach very similar to one described in this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48113625/5741205):

```
val cols = df.select(df.columns.map(c => count(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
             .collect()(0)
             .toSeq.zipWithIndex
             .filter(_._1 != 0).map(_._2)
             .map(i => df.columns.apply(i))
```

this gives us an array of columns, that we were looking for:

```
scala> cols
res125: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(int1, str1, dt1)
```

now we can select those columns:

```
scala> df.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).show
+----+------+--------------------+
|int1|  str1|                 dt1|
+----+------+--------------------+
|   1|strin1|                null|
|null|  null|2000-01-03 12:12:...|
+----+------+--------------------+
```

or

```
scala> df.select(cols.map(col): _*).show
+----+------+--------------------+
|int1|  str1|                 dt1|
+----+------+--------------------+
|   1|strin1|                null|
|null|  null|2000-01-03 12:12:...|
+----+------+--------------------+
```